Inkscape - Interpolate sub-paths are deformed
I have an inner path and an outer path in a 'L' shape and combined the paths. Then I rounded all corners. Then I added "interpolate sub-paths".
The new inner paths are a bit warped and not smoothly following the outer and inner shape as expected. I cannot figure out how to correct this.
All the spacing between nodes and corner radii are symmetric.
Also when experimenting with another shape this happens (see figures).


My goal is to make similar drawings like this one:


It cannot be done ok by using interpolation, because node distributions along path length vary. In practice  interpolation creates easy to predict and strictly regular looking results between non-equal paths if the paths have only 2 or 3 nodes. Pattern along path is not any better for your case.
You can get it right if you make separate curved and straight blocks with exactly fitting ends.

In the left an exact 90 degrees section of a circle is separated and a scaled (smaller) copy of it is made. Both must be paths, so a circle is drawn and converted to path and then split at 9 and 12 o'clock nodes.
In the right the arcs are aligned to the bottom and the right and extension Generate from path > Interpolate paths is used to make the curved section. The result must at first be ungrouped and then grouped together with the originals to keep all easily together.
The same is done to 2 equally long horizontal line segments. There's no need to interpolate. You can as well draw to the ends of the arcs and finally align the right end nodes of the lines. Have snaps ON to get the spacing of the lines exact when you draw to the ends of the arcs.
Make flipped and rotated copies of the arc groups and line groups. You can scale the line lengths, but you cannot scale the arcs. Here's a random collection of copies:

These parts snap together easily and you can get for example this:

You can join the parts together easily. Select all groups and ungroup. Then select all and after it turn on the node tool.
Select all intermediate joint nodes, but no endpoints by dragging and click "join selected nodes". The joined nodes are blue in the next image:

Joining is useful for coloring and stroke style adjustments. And, of course, if you want closed paths.
You can succeed also by using effects for rounding and making offset paths as long as you work with closed paths and you do not try to interpolate between paths which have different node distributions. You can instead use path effect Offset and make the multiple copies manually.

Create the closed base loop with the pen by clicking only. Then apply the corners effect to get rounded corners.
Convert the result to path. Let's call it here path A.
Duplicate A. Insert path effect Offset to the duplicate. Let the offset be say 1 millimeter. Copy the result to the clipboard.
Paste in place a new copy of A with offset. Adjust the offset to 2 mm
Paste in place a new copy of A with offset. Adjust the offset to 3 mm
Add more copies of A with wider offsets if needed

In the next image there's the base loop, the same with rounded corners+converted to path and a version with -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 millimeter offsets.

The offset paths are inserted one by one as described above. As you see, the crossing unfortunately is not the same as what's got by drawing the paths as blocks like shown in the beginning of this answer. But it can be useful anyway and the problem does not exist if the path doesn't cross itself.
